# Function with arguments (prime numbers)

Tags: ruby

I want a ruby program, it have 2 Arguments(a,b) ,which output the Prime
numbers between a and b. here is my program. but it's wrong. i don't know
where is the problem. can anyone help me?

```
a,b=ARGV
def prime (a,b)
for i in 2..b
  f=true
    for p in 2...i
      if i%p==0
        f =!f
        break
      end
   end
 print i, "--" if f  
end
end
sushu=prime(a,b)
p "the prime zweischen #{a} and #{b} is #{sushu}."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers already pointed out what is wrong with your code (using strings instead of integers and not using the argument `a`. However, if you are on Ruby 1.9, there's a much easier way to achieve what you want:

```
require 'prime'
def prime(a, b)
  (a..b).select(&:prime?)
end

prime(1,20)
#=> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not consider the in parameter a. Probably changing i to iterate from `a..b`, instead of `..b` will fix your problem.

```
a,b=ARGV
def prime (a,b)
for i in a..b
  f=true
    for p in 2...i
      if i%p==0
        f =!f
        break
      end
   end
 print i, "--" if f  
end
end
sushu=prime(a,b)
p "the prime zweischen #{a} and #{b} is #{sushu}."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sushu=prime(a.to_i,b.to_i)
```